# ASP.NET Repeater control with nested repeaters

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have a nested repeater control. Here is what the HTML looks like:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="boxLeft">
        <h4><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DisciplineName") %></h4><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDisciplineID" Visible="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DisciplineID") %>'></asp:Label>
        <p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DisciplineNarrative") %></p>
        <h5 class="articles"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InstructorCount")%> instructors</h5>
        <ul>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptRegions">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><a href='/Lessons/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DisciplineName") %>/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CityName") %>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CityName") %></a></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

As you can see, I want to access the parent DisciplineName property from the parent repeater, in my child repeater in order to build the URL. I get the following error:

> DataBinding: 'GolfLessonSearch.Model.CityEntity' does not contain a
>   property with the name 'DisciplineName'.

This is because it is trying to get "DisciplineName" from the child repeater but I want it from the parent repeater. I thought that the properties may still be in scope but it appears not. Is there any way of getting this?

Comment: will this work for you? DataBinder.Eval(((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent).DataItem , "DisciplineName")      I am not sure whether this will work or not. SO I am putting this as comment instead of answer

Comment: @Pavan Will need to be Container.Parent.Parent (The first Parent is the Repeater you are in), but otherwise your suggestion works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the objects behind your DataItems have the same parent/child relationship as you are trying to represent them in the repeater, you can always fully qualify the property name so that your child repeater is calling

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Parent.DisciplineName")
```

If this isn't the case, my gut would be to create a ViewModel object (even though it's not mvc) of your child object to fake that relationship...

**EDIT**

Just a note that when I said "Parent.DisciplineName", I meant to replace "Parent" with the object name... (I only qualify because "Parent" is a reserved word in so many other places in asp.net...